Datastream using private connectivity
You can help me, please?
I have try to create the reverse proxy to make connection from Datastream VPC to CloudSQL.
The VM is close connection with CloudSQL database, but when i run the "Test connection profile" in Datastream, result is "Timeout expired".
So, you can help me a create the reverse proxy?
Thank u so much.
Connect Datastream to CloudSQL.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you need to create nat vm with this guide in order to use private connectivity so you dont need to use external ip from cloud sql
https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/private-connectivity#whatsnext
